# Schedule .sql file

Tags: sql, windows, scheduler

I need to **schedule a .sql file**. (that executes some queries)
I have sql express so I can not use SQL Agent because I have SQL Express so I wish to use **Windows scheduler**. 
But the schedule just opens the file **without execute it**.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to call SQLCMD.EXE together with the related parameter.
For example:

```
SQLCMD.EXE -S .\sqlexpress -E -i C:\temp\myfile.sql
```

For a detailed explanation plese have a look at [this blog post](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/02/14/howto-quick-amp-dirty-sql-express-scheduled-backup)